# Java File I/O - Text File - How to check for content?

Tags: java, file-io

I was wondering, If i had a java class, that wanted to consult a txt file with say a list of names like

```
tom
steve
jones
```

how could i open the text file in the java program and basically see if a string contained in the program matches one of these names?

so far i have come up with

```
                try {
                BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("users.txt"));

                while (inputReader.readLine() != null){

                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException ep) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                p.printStackTrace();
            }
```

but do not no where to go from here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the result of `readLine()`, like:

```
String nextLine;
while ((nextLine = inputReader.readLine()) != null){
if (nextLine.equals(stringToCheck)) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

(where `stringToCheck` is the target string, of course.)

Comment: +1. my two cents: equals, equalsIgnoreCase, contains or even regular expressions via Pattern.compile are your friends for string-matching

Comment: Maybe it contained whitespace. Just call `trim()` before `equals()`. I.e. `if (nextLine.trim().equals(stringToCheck)) {}`